# When content larger then container, container has white space on the right

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
        background-color:darkorange;
    }
    .content {
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">Some text</div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Resize the browser under 960px. If you scroll horizontal .container will have on the right a white space instead of being darkorange all the way to the right.

**How ca I make .container to be darkorange without a white space on the right when you resize the browser under 960px and scroll horizontal?**

Comment: You've hard-coded .content NOT to be 100% width, of course you are going to have space on wider screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the container a minimum width of 960px;

```
.container {
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

The container by default will be 100% of it's container (the body), which is the width of the window. When the window is less than 960px, the content overflows the container so you see the body's background color showing through.